# How to fix WebCore crashes in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My app makes heavy use of `UIWebView`'s in iOS 7 and 8.  I get frequent crash reports affecting a small number of users relating to Web Core.  I have already been setting the webview delegate to nil when its view controller disappears, as suggested in other answers.  However, I still get numerous crashes like:

```
WebCore::SharedBuffer::clear()
WebCore::TimerBase::updateHeapIfNeeded(double)
WebCore::WebVideoFullscreenModelMediaElement::updateForEventName
WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::seekTimerFired
WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners
WebCore::CachedResource::unregisterHandle
WebCore::CSSFontSelector::~CSSFontSelector()
WebCore::MediaQueryMatcher::styleResolverChanged
```

I have a few thousand daily users, but get probably 5 crashes a day with stack traces like the above, so I'm never able to reproduce.  What else can I do to prevent `UIWebView` crashes?

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133366
Maybe not..

Comment: @Erich I am also facing issue like WebCore::WebVideoFullscreenModelMediaElement::updateForEventName  Crash issue occur in iOs8. So kindly send me answer or suggestion if you solve it.

Comment: Also having many of these strange crashes.

Comment: I guess you already tried stopping loading and loading an empty page when navigation is done? The only reasonable suggestion than would be to add more analytics so you can try to get more context around the crash or use services similar to http://appsee.com maybe that will spread some light on your user's behaviour. Although crashes like that are usually a dead end until Apple updates WebKit in the next release

Answer (score 2):

Are you using UIWebView instances with delegate in some places?, did you try to nil the delegate in the dealloc method of the view controller or view?

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.webView.delegate = nil;
}
```

No matter if you are using ARC or non-ARC, this is very important.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned I am niling the delegate

Comment: Hi Erich, if you know the url, or file you are trying to load, is the best way to reproduce. If it's a url save the response as a file and try to render, working with the file will be more easy reducing and checking any html syntax. If you can provide the file or url I can do it too :). I have this crashes in past using complex HTML pages.

Comment: `@property (nullable, nonatomic, assign) id <UIWebViewDelegate> delegate;`
Apple set this `delegate` to `assign` (not weak) so it may cause wild pointer promblem.
iOS 13 SDK still has this promblem